# Assist with js output and html output stored in var

Tags: javascript, html

Hello I am trying to store some html output in a JS var to output it to the page using "getElementById"...

The problem I am having is with single quotes versus double quotes and when to wrap them within each other...

here is my code:

```
var buttonOutput1="<br/>";
var buttonOutput2="<button onclick="DealCard('player')">Hit</button>";
var buttonOutput5=buttonOutput1+buttonOutput2;

document.getElementById('buttonArea').innerHTML = buttonOutput5;
```

I know a little about this, I know you can enclose something within single quotes and then enclose that within double quotes and it all works fine.

But because I want to store it all in a variable, I need to enclose it all in a third set of quotes and so therein is my problem.

So just stuck on what I should do here, wondering if anyone can help on this.

Thanks,  G

**** My solution 12:51PM EST ****

Was able figure this out by breaking it into pieces:

```
var buttonOutput1="<br/>";
var buttonOutput2a="DealCard('player')";
var buttonOutput2b='<button onclick="' + buttonOutput2a + '">Hit 
Me</button>';
var buttonOutput5=buttonOutput1+buttonOutput2b;





document.getElementById('buttonArea').innerHTML = buttonOutput5;
```

Comment: If your target browsers support ECMAScript 6(https://caniuse.com/#feat=template-literals), you can use ` ` backticks(https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals), that will allow you to mix double and single quotes with no need to escaping.

Comment: Thanks so much yuriy - I figured it out a different way right after writing this, but I will be looking at your input - the way i got it to work was splitting it into pieces and multiple steps - I am sure your way is better so I will be looking at it. I will update my question with my new code...

Answer (score 2):

You can create a DOM node using create Element (DOM Level 2) and attach a function to the onclick attribute.

```js
var domNode = document.createElement('button');
domNode.innerHTML = 'Click me';
domNode.onclick = function() {
  alert("hello world")
};

document.getElementById('hook').appendChild(domNode);
```

```html
<div id="hook"></div>
```